# match a parent element

Tags: html, css

Home to write a selector which match an element `F` such that `F` is parent of `E`. More precisely I have a markup:

```
<div>
    <p class="someclass">Some text</p>
</div>
```

And I need to match `div` element which is parent of `p.someclass`.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: It's not possible yet (at least with pure CSS), maybe it will be available in CSS4.

Comment: You can use jQuery to add a class to the parent element and just style that class?

`$(".someclass").parent().addClass("yournewclass");`

Comment: sans jQuery: el.parentNode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not currently possible in CSS. Here is a jQuery function that should do the trick:

```
$('div > p.someclass').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().css('property', 'value');
});
```

Here is a shorter version of the above example:

```
$('div > p.someclass').parent().css('property', 'value');
```